# Optimizing bit-matching performance using AVX compiler intrinsic

Tags: c++, performance, x86

We are working on a complicated math problem, very detailed question with description of the problem is here: [C++ multi-threaded determination of curling numbers in vectors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252718/c-multi-threaded-determination-of-curling-numbers-in-vectors).

That code is now converted to use 256-bit registers to store the bit sequences. Profiling pointed to one function taking over 85% of the total CPU time. I have extracted that function into a test project.

The time-critical function is counting repeated bit patterns at the end of a 256-bit sequence. For example, `0b1000100010001000` have tree `0` at the end, and four `1000`. We are looking for a highest frequency, so 4 in this case. We are not interested in the pattern length below 10, or the frequencies over 4. The test case used below is

```
// sequence with 84 '0' and 1 '1', repeated three times
__m256i seq = _mm256_set_epi64x(0x00000000'00000000, 0x00000400'00000000,
                                0x00000000'00200000, 0x00000000'00000001);
```

The development is done on MS Visual Studio 2019, will possibly also run on Linux.

To speed things up, we are using AVX intrinsics.

We are pre-computing all bit masks for 128-bit registers. Attempted to calculate the mask as needed to avoid going to memory, but it was slower.

Our estimate is that the entire program would solve the problem in weeks, so we are looking for any kind of performance improvement.

Please note that we already utilize all available CPU cores, that run the same function with different arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <chrono>

// ShiftRight is my adaptation from http://notabs.org/lfsr/software/
static void bitShiftRight256ymm(__m256i* data, int count)
{
  __m256i innerCarry = _mm256_slli_epi64(*data, 64 - count);             // carry outs in bit 0 of each qword
  __m256i rotate = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(innerCarry, 0x39);           // rotate ymm right 64 bits
  innerCarry = _mm256_blend_epi32(_mm256_setzero_si256(), rotate, 0x3F); // clear upper qword
  *data = _mm256_srli_epi64(*data, count);                               // shift all qwords right
  *data = _mm256_or_si256(*data, innerCarry);                            // propagate carrys
}
// shifts right by exactly 64 bits
static void shiftRight64(__m256i* data) {
  *data = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(*data, 0x39);                   // rotate ymm right 64 bits
  *data = _mm256_blend_epi32(_mm256_setzero_si256(), *data, 0x3F); // clear high qword
}
// handle shifts over 64 bits
static void bitShiftRight256ymm_long(__m256i* data, int count)
{
  shiftRight64(data);
  if(count > 64)
    bitShiftRight256ymm(data, count - 64);
}

// mask of 64 to select smaller parts of the sequence
static const uint64_t mask64[65] = { 0,
 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xF, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF,
 0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF, 0xFFFF,
 0x1FFFF, 0x3FFFF, 0x7FFFF, 0xFFFFF, 0x1FFFFF, 0x3FFFFF, 0x7FFFFF, 0xFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
};

// mask of 128 to select larger parts of the sequence, built at start
static __m128i mask128[129] = {};
void build_mask()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    mask128[i] = i < 64 ?
    _mm_set_epi64x(0, mask64[i % 64]) :
    _mm_set_epi64x(mask64[(i - 64) % 64], mask64[64]);

  mask128[128] = _mm_set_epi64x(mask64[64], mask64[64]);
}

// check if the last 'length' bits in 'src' and 'target' are equal
bool masked128eq(const __m128i* src, int length, const __m128i* target) {
  __m128i neq = _mm_xor_si128(*src, *target);
  return (_mm_test_all_zeros(neq, mask128[length]));
}

// count max repeated bit patterns at the end of the sequence
int count_freq(const __m256i& seq) {
  int max_freq = 1;
  __m128i seq128 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(seq);
  unsigned char upper_limit = 256 / (max_freq + 1);

  for (int pattern_length = 10; pattern_length <= upper_limit; ++pattern_length) {
    int freq = 1;
    __m256i temp = seq;
    int matching_length = 2 * pattern_length;
    while (matching_length <= 256) {                    // while we are within range of the sequence length
      if(pattern_length < 64)
        bitShiftRight256ymm(&temp, pattern_length);     // shift the copy of sequence by pattern_length bits
      else
        bitShiftRight256ymm_long(&temp, pattern_length);// shift the copy of sequence by pattern_length bits

      __m128i t128 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(temp);
      if (!masked128eq(&t128, pattern_length, &seq128)) // check if the two parts are equal
        break;
      if (++freq > max_freq) {
        max_freq = freq;
        upper_limit = 256 / (max_freq + 1);
        if (max_freq > 3) {                             // don't care for frequencies over 4
          return max_freq;
        }
        matching_length += pattern_length;
      }
    }
 }
  return max_freq;
}

// sequence with 84 '0' and 1 '1', repeated three times
__m256i seq = _mm256_set_epi64x(0x00000000'00000000, 0x00000400'00000000, 0x00000000'00200000, 0x00000000'00000001);

int main() {
  build_mask();
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  int f(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i) {
    f += count_freq(seq);
  }
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
  return f;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Implemented some micro-optimization, with a modest speed-up:

1. Dropped calls to `_mm256_blend_epi32` in both shift functions, as we don't care about the garbage "shifted in"; we will only use the "good" part on the right.
2. Split `for (int pattern_length = 10; pattern_length <= upper_limit; ++pattern_length)` loop into two identical loops, one going up to 64, and the second - over64, to avoid testing for `if(pattern_length < 64)` in each iteration.

Comment: This could use more description of what is the point of your code. "The function is counting repeated bit patterns at the end of a 256-bit sequence" — that's better than no description at all, but much worse than it could be. Maybe it would help to explain why on the third line you wrote `max_freq + 1` instead of `2`, for example. Or show some example inputs and outputs — `assert(count_freq(x) == y)` for some known pairs `x,y`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone - That a fair request. I will work on improving the description. It's always a balance between "just enough" and "too much information" :)  The `max_freq + 1` was used for consistency with the in-loop recalculation. The compiler figured out it's `2` before the loop.

Comment: Couldn't you use AVX512?

Comment: @ALX23z we sure can; are there any faster bit-shifting instructions available on AVX512? Our sequence at the moment fits into 256 bits.

Comment: What's this doing?  Counting number of trailing 1s in a `__m256i`?  Clearly something more complicated, but it's hard to understand without any surrounding code that would motivate why you want it.  Re: AVX512: is `_mm256_lzcnt_epi64` (AVX512CD) a useful building block? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vplzcntd:vplzcntq.  Every CPU with AVX512F also has AVX512CD, and SIMD lzcnt runs fast.

Comment: @PeterCordes - we are looking for a repeated bit patterns at the end of the bit sequence in `const __m256i& seq`. For example, `0b1000100010001000` have tree `0` at the end, and four `1000`. We are looking for a highest frequency, so 4 in this case. The test case used above is `// sequence with 84 '0' and 1 '1', repeated three times`. I have compressed the problem into this short code fragment; the original, very detailed question is here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252718/c-multi-threaded-determination-of-curling-numbers-in-vectors

Comment: ok, good, that's the kind of thing @Quuxplusone was asking for.  Edit that into your question in a spot where future readers will see it easily, especially the link to the other code review.

Comment: `vplzcntq` could possibly help with this: after xoring with a repeated pattern, you could lzcnt to find the position of the first mismatch: where it stops matching.  (If you build a 256-bit lzcnt out of vplzcntq's 64-bit chunks).  But IDK if you can create inputs for that method efficiently; it requires broadcasting an n-bit pattern instead of right-shifting repeatedly only when you do actually get a match.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you suggesting to use `vplzcntq` instead of masking here `return (_mm_test_all_zeros(neq, mask128[length]));`? Would I need *trailing* zeroes? Unfortunately, my processor doesn't support AVX512, so I can't test it...

Comment: Well you could maybe start from the top bits, since lzcnt naturally starts from that side, otherwise yeah you'd have to bit-reverse the input once so the top is the original bottom.  It's not at all a drop-in replacement for anything you're currently doing, you'd want to redesign an algorithm to take advantage of it.  But without an easy way to broadcast multiple copies of the low or high `n` bits, there's no easy way to take advantage.  If you want to play with it on a computer without AVX512, for eventual deployment on one that does, use Intel's SDE (software development emulator).

Comment: Also, your edit to the question still didn't include an example.  And the link is missing the https so it's not clickable.  Maybe you copy/pasted the formatted text of your comment instead of using the edit link on the question to get the original markdown...  You have to proofread for that.  Also, you put it in one of many tiny paragraphs where it's kind of buried.  The actual purpose and example should be higher up so readers know what this is all about before they get into other details.